# Sql server convert datetime to ''YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server, I have a column `start_date` in `Table1` (2 values shown below)

```
'2006-08-15 00:00:00.000',
'2010-07-13 18:53:59.000'
```

I want to convert these dates to format "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".

I have tried both of the following things:

1. `Select Convert(varchar, start_date, 126) + 'Z' as required_date from Table1`
2. `Select Convert(varchar, start_date, 127) + 'Z' as required_date from Table1`

I get these results:

```
'2006-08-15T00:00:00Z'
'2010-07-13 18:53:59Z'
```

Last 000 is getting trimmed out (that should not happen).

I want result like this:

```
'2006-08-15T00:00:00.000Z'
'2010-07-13 18:53:59.000Z'
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: [Bad Habits to kick: Declaring varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: if you don't care about the 'T', you can use format code 121 to always have the milliseconds, but as stated in the answer they're absent when the value is 0. the timezone component (Z etc) will only come in with the `datetimeoffset` type I believe.

Comment: You forgot a critical piece of information that is always missing in these date format type questions: what data type is `start_date`. Also a datetime is always best kept in a datetime data type. Imposing a format means you are converting it to a string. Can you give some background on why it needs a certain format?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to sql but I assume that the removal of .000 is because of sql itself not showing milliseconds or whatever that is. Try adding '.000Z' where you add 'Z' and you should have it?

Should look like this

```
Select Convert(varchar,start_date,126)+'.000Z' as required_date from Table1

Select Convert(varchar,start_date,127)+'.000Z' as required_date from Table1
```

Comment: Thanks @Ineffable21, But I am looking for the dynamic one. Just gave here 2 examples but I could have values other than 000 too. That time it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```
Select Convert(varchar(25),start_date,121)+'Z' as required_date from Table1
```

Some good explanation here [SQL Convert Date functions and formats](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-convert-date-functions-and-formats/)

Comment: Thanks huMpty duMpty, but 'T' is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I can see only one way to get the desired answer:

Select
CONVERT(varchar(20),start_date,126)+
substring(CONVERT(varchar(35),start_date,121),20,23)+'Z'
AS required_date from Table1

Please comment if any optimized way.